# Section-wise trendlines in a Chart in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I know how I can add a trendline over a whole data series:
[image]

But is there an easy way to create section-wise trend lines (including forecast) ?

i.e. I'm aiming at something similar to this:

[image]

I know, that I could get that by splitting the data into multiple series, but is there a way to keep the data in one series but limit which points contribute to the trend-line ?

> **Edit:**
>   The application would be a auto-updating chart where one continuously adds data-points but wants to see trends, and trend-changes over time.
>   Imagine data collected as endless list of "Date" "Value" with potentially several entries per day. One wants to plot the "sum-values" per day - easily achieved with a pivot-chart, but then also wants to see trend-lines for each month in that chart.

Comment: If you don't have multiple series, how is Excel supposed to "know" which point to associate with which trendline?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad By being able to define ranges? i.e. I want ot assing row [1...100] as data, but then be able to create a trendline with the data [1..20] only, and another one with [21..40] etc.  If it would be PivotChart, it would be useful to show monthly data but create trendlines for each year f.e.

Comment: If you don't want to divide the data into ranges, each as a separate series, copy the desired points for each segment to a new series.  Use no point markers.  Plot everything together and the new series won't show.  Then fit a trendline to each new series.

Comment: I ll try that. But if it works, why have you posted it as comment not as answer? But I guess it still shows up in the legend.

Comment: I posted it as a comment because it isn't really clear what objective you're trying to accomplish or issue you're trying to avoid, so I don't know if it is a relevant solution.  It lets you see all the original data with uniform markers but separate trend lines.  If your concern is the legend, yeah, all of that will show up there.  It would help if you edit the question to clarify the objective you need to achieve.

Comment: @fixer1234 I thought the question is rather precise and clear "is there a way to keep the data in one series but limit which points contribute to the trend-line ?" - Of course, the answer may be equally clear: "No, Excel can't do this." Is It?

Comment: That part is clear.  Doing exactly that in that way isn't natively supported, but there are various workarounds to get an equivalent result.  You could just divide the data into 2 series, but there's some reason you don't want to do that.  If we know your constraints on "equivalent", that can guide suggesting a workaround.  For example, if the issue is that you want all the markers to look the same, that can be fixed.  If the issue is the legend, most workarounds would probably have the same issue, but there might be a solution for the legend.  A workaround is better than "no".

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. Yes, I was mainly looking for "natively supported" because I wanted to use this in auto-updating chart / pivot-charts. That's why all sorts of manually regrouping isn't really feasible, and super-convoluted scripted solutions are not worth the effort. (Using different software then). Easiest example: Have data points "per date" with multiple entries per day - want to created pivot-chart plotting daily-sum values and trend-lines for each month (in one chart)

Comment: Yeah, auto-updating is a tough one.  It could be done with VBA (which is natively supported, but not an out-of-the-box solution), which could be triggered by a change in the data.  So it would effectively be auto-updating, but would require some initial coding.  It wouldn't hurt to add the info from your comment into the question.  There's a chance somebody has already done something similar.